# Can you boot the RPI 3 or below from SPI EEPROM?

Tags: boot, pi-zero, spi

RPI4 has an eeprom, however the other versions don't. I would be interested in particular in the RPI Zero.

Could you add an SPI EEPROM to the header/gpio pins in order to load u-boot or maybe even a kernel from it?
A similar setup for other boards can be found here:

https://linux-sunxi.org/Bootable_SPI_flash

The header on the RPI has pins for SPI exposed, however, I don't know if they can be used for booting.